# Ember Data - How to deserialize model.serialize()?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In Ember Data 3.24, if you do

```
foo = record.serialize()
```

how can you reverse the process?  i.e. deserialize the JS object in foo and update the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse process for `Model.serialize()` is [`Store.pushPayload()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.24/classes/Store/methods/push?anchor=pushPayload):

```js
// push some sample data into Ember Data's store
this.store.push({
  data: {
    type: 'post',
    id: '1',
    attributes: {
      title: 'foo',
    },
  },
});

// get the record    
const record = this.store.peekRecord('post', '1');

// serialize the record
const serialized = record.serialize({ includeId: true });

// manipulate the record to see the update
// this assumes that the application uses the default JSON:API serializer
serialized.data.attributes.title = 'bar';

// push the new state into the store again
this.store.pushPayload('post', serialized);

// verify that the update is reflected in Ember Data's store
console.log(record.title); // "bar"
```

Please note that `Store.pushPayload()` does *not* return the records which are were in the payload.

If you want to push a record into the store and get that one, you can use [`Store.push()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.24/classes/Store/methods/push?anchor=push). But that one expects a normalized JSON:API document following the internal conventions of Ember Data.

A payload could be normalized to a JSON:API document following the internal conventions of Ember Data with the [`Serializer.normalizeResponse()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.24/classes/Serializer/methods/normalizeResponse?anchor=normalizeResponse) method. But it has a complex arguments interface, which does not fit well with the day-to-day usage of Ember Data.

```js
// manipulate serialized state
serialized.data.attributes.title = 'baz';

// normalize the payload to JSON:API document following Ember Data's conventions
const store = this.store;
const model = this.store.modelFor('post');
const normalized = this.store.serializerFor('post').normalizeResponse(this.store, PostModel, serialized, undefined, 'findRecord');

// push it into the store
const result = this.store.push(normalized);

// verify that store has been updated
console.log(record.title); // "baz"

// Store.push() returns the record
console.log(record === result);
```

If only dealing with one record and not needing a fully reverse function, you may also use [`Store.normalize()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.24/classes/Store/methods/normalize?anchor=normalize). Assuming that your application uses JSON:API serializer the payload could also be normalized like this:

```js
const normalized = this.store.normalize('post', serialized.data);
this.store.push(normalized);
```

Comment: Ok, so after testing, this only seems to work when a record is in the saved state.  For example, save() must be called on a record created using createRecord().  Is there a function that accepts the same arguments as createRecord that imitates store.push()?  Or a way to set the state of the record as saved without calling the async save() function?  (I am only saving records locally at the moment)

Comment: You may run into the wrong direction. You can customize Ember Data to persist data in local storage or IndexDB. There are two community addons, which claim to provide such adapter: [ember-localstorage-adapter](https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter) and [ember-indexeddb-adapter](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-indexeddb-adapter). But haven't used them myself.

Comment: I'm already using ember-localstorage-adapter.  But the same issue remains - either async save is required or a push where the arguments are in a different form.  I could write a function to convert the arguments to the push form but want to see if there's a better solution first

Comment: Although it looks as though pushPayload might be the answer